# Leaving death site after final rites without taking leave

Tags: death, vedic-rituals, afterlife

Following death/ obsequies and  even after Punyahavachanam is performed there is a custom among some sections of society: the  visiting relations or  guests leave the place without saying so or taking leave from the host.

Maybe a vague feeling of being followed by a still active restless spirit. The origin of such practice seems elusive.

Is there a mention made about preferential action of the prethatma on guests and visitors... in Rigveda / Garuda Purana etc. under any circumstances of demise?